# Cannot create the same #temp table twice in the same batch

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Wrote a very simple test case in SQLServer and don't quite understand why it doesn't work:

```
create table #temp(
  id int,
  val int)

insert into #temp values (1, 1), (2, 2)
select * from #temp

if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
   drop table #temp

create table #temp(
  id int,
  val int)

insert into #temp values (1, 1), (2, 2)
select * from #temp
```

Comment: post your error message...

Comment: You haven't included any information about what is wrong here. You've said "it doesn't work" with no information about what that means. You obviously have a reason to think it "doesn't work". Is there a reason you're withholding that information from us? Please [edit] your question to include it. It's your task to explain the problem you're having so that we can try to help you solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see [the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), which states:

> If more than one temporary table is created inside a single stored procedure or batch, they must have different names.

Your code yields the following error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   
> There is already an object named '#temp' in the database.

And this is not because the table has been dropped and can't be re-created; this code never gets executed, the parser actually sees you trying to create the same table twice (and it has no ability to see logic like your `DROP` command).

Other than using two different #temp table names, another workaround would be to just create the table once, and truncate it when you're done with your first bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature by design and is clarified by Microsoft against Microsoft Connect BugID 666430

A case study on the same issue is given at : [temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created](http://www.tectalks.com/493/temporary-table-could-not-be-re-created/)